# ModuleNotFoundError while importing a class from different app

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my django project LibraryManagement I have two apps 'book' and 'authors'. I am trying to establish relationship between two apps using foreign key. While I try to import class Authors in the book I got error ModuleNotFound:No module named 'LibraryManagement.authors'

Below is my project structure

```
LMS
 -LibraryManagement
   -authors
   -book
   -LibraryManagement
 -venv
```

Code of models.py from authors app

```
from django.db import models

class Authors(models.Model):
   author_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
```

Code of models.py from book app

```
from django.db import models
from LibraryManagement.authors.models import Authors

class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Authors)
    remarks = models.TextField(max_length=300)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating those files within packages. Packages in python only works with a `__init__.py` file inside it.
So, if you want to be able to do:

```
from LibraryManagement.authors
```

LibraryManagement has to have a `__init__.py` file within it. The same happens within "authors". It has to have a `__init__.py` file so you can import it as a package.

The `__init__.py` file can be empty, but they have to exist.

Comment: While creating the project I had used the code 'django-admin startproject LibraryManagement' so the LibraryManagement needs to be a directory which contains 'LibraryManagement' package and apps: 'book' and 'authors'.